Do we want to enable an "AI-generated content" banner?
Given the recent announcement Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content and given our stance in Should posts generated with the help of AI be marked as AI-generated content? and How to warn users about AI generated content?, it seems likely to me that we'd appreciate "a reduction in posts flagged for AI-generated content". (Happily, we haven't yet seen a large number of such posts).
I'll put two "voting" posts as Answers, one for each of the "yes" options:

**Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on [Site Name]. Learn more
**Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools must be cited on [Site Name]. Learn more

... but please add a separate Answer if you disagree with this idea for any reason!
The banner would then appear exactly at the point where it would be necessary to inform potential AI posters about how things (should) work here:


Thanks for taking the time to post this. I've voted for not allowing Artificial Intelligence generated answers in our site, my reasoning being that it hasn't served us very well so far and adds a lot of overhead for moderation. It is much easier to blanket ban them altogether, allowing us to just delete such posts, than what we currently have in place to keep track of them. Whoever wants AI generated answers can go directly to any AI model site.

Thanks also.. I'm assuming 'Not Allowed' does not exclude answers whose origin  may be  in AI, but which have subsequently been thoroughly tested and edited accordingly by a human. Those should be virtually impossible to detect in any case.

@RobinBetts I think if no one can really detect that an answer was written with the help of AI, there is no reason to intervene, because then a human has obviously written/edited a meaningful answer to the best of their knowledge and belief, which should also be correct in terms of content.

I've read an AI-generated answer on LinkedIn regarding UV splits at hard edges. Despite being the first hit on Google, it was literally useless. Nothing more than "perfect" paragraphs stuffed with utterly irrelevant fluff (it felt like reading a Facebook post by a crypto scammer). Then I read a human-written article on Polycount about the same topic. It was SOLID GOLD. No comparison. Needless to say, I gave LinkedIn and Google an earful regarding their folly in pushing AI.

@TitaniusAnglesmith I absolutely agree with you! The (most) AI translation mechanisms actually work very well. This is precisely why they are not a problem, because the translated content is actually flawless and understandable. What is problematic, as you rightly point out, is AI-generated content that is primarily the result of AI influence. In other words, content that simply generates seemingly plausible content in an obtuse manner, but which would never stand up to a practical test.

Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed
I think we should have this banner added:

Reminder: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on [Site Name]. Learn more


This banner has now been enabled on Blender SE!

Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools must be cited
I think we should have this banner added:

Reminder: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools must be cited on [Site Name]. Learn more

